# Count set of elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count

i have numpy array

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 5],
       [3, 4, 6],
       [2, 5, 4],
       [5, 4, 3],
       [3, 5, 1],
       [2, 5, 1]])
```

i want function to count how many times set of values appears in array. For example

```
count_set([1,2]) 

#output 
3

# because set[1,2] appears in elements 0,1,6
```

I have tried some np.notezero , but it doesnt workout

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcasted comparison with [`all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html)/[`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html):

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [1, 2, 5],
              [3, 4, 6],
              [2, 5, 4],
              [5, 4, 3],
              [3, 5, 1],
              [2, 5, 1]])

def count_set(a, elems):
    return (a[..., None]==elems).any(-2).all(-1).sum()

count_set(a, [1, 2])
# 3
```

Comment: it totaly works good, can you explaine how does it work ?

Comment: @Karapet sure, the broadcasted comparison performs a comparison of all values with both 1 and 2 resulting in a 3D array (of shape m,n,2 assuming an input shape of m,n). We then check if there is at least one match per row for each tested value (`any`) and if all tested values have a match (`all`). This output a 1D boolean array with `True` for all rows that have such a match. By using `sum` we count them. I recommend you run each step of `a[..., None]==elems).any(-2).all(-1)` to see for yourself.